# Does constant heavy usage of the RAM deteriorate it significantly faster?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

Simply put, I am wondering whether constantly (as in ~13h/day) having ~80% pressure on the RAM will deteriorate it faster.

I am not asking for insignificant results - for example if it makes it live a day less, this is not what I am asking for.

I am just worried that the practice I am employing right now may be causing long term damage to the RAM - please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you asking, does the fact that OS consider value stored in some RAM pages useful, rather than garbage, affect RAM lifetime?

Comment: I don't know the technical terms that much, but the way you say it makes it sound like it does not affect RAM life. @PetSerAl

Comment: I'd say it doesn't make any difference because it is refreshed at a fixed rate either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your conditions, it shouldn't be a problem. Good RAM modules are designed to be used continuously and remain filled with bits.

This can be understood as follows:

The RAM module essentially consists of transistors and capacitors. A bit is stored in the capacitor as a "charged" state. Due to leakage, the capacitors are dynamically charged and recharged by the transistor (which is why it is called DRAM or Dynamic Random Access Memory). Thus, each transistor-capacitor pair stores one bit. Now coming to the point, having a charge inside the capacitor wouldn't destroy it (and transistors practically last forever).

Now here's the catch: this assumes perfect voltage, temperature and EMI situations. To be secure, be sure of the following:

**1) Use a good power supply**.  That should keep your RAM (and by the way your entire system) healthy.

2) Use a proper metal case for the system. This helps keep out EMI.

**3) Use proper cooling**. Prolonged heating of the module would definitely cause significant damage. If you are using RAM modules with heat sinks, this shouldn't be a problem either. Either way, keep them ventilated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I understand from this that in general, using RAM a lot will not significantly affect its lifetime. Thank your for clearing it up.

Comment: I'm using a MacBook Air though- how do you think this applies to it?

Comment: A MacBook would probably have a very good charger (seeing the cost you paid for it) and proper shielding. You should worry about cooling though, and you're going to spoil the battery if you keep it plugged in forever.